# Using dplyr, count non-numeric grades in each class

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Given the input and code below, using dplyr and groups, how can I produce the results shown in the output? I know how to sum columns in groups using dplyr, but in this case I need to count how many of each non-numeric grade occurred in each class.

```
**INPUT**
Class Student   Grade
1       Jack    C
1       Mary    B
1       Mo      B
1       Jane    A
1       Tom     C
2       Don     C
2       Betsy   B
2       Sue     C
2       Tayna   B
2       Kim     C
```

```
**CODE**
  # Create the dataframe 
    Class <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
    Name <- c("Jack", "Mary", "Mo", "Jane", "Tom", "Don", "Betsy", "Sue", "Tayna", "Kim")
    Grade <- c("C","B","B","A","C","C","B","C","B","C")
    StudentGrades <- data.frame(Class, Name, Grade)
```

```
**OUTPUT**
Class   Grade-A Grade-B Grade-C
1       1       2       2
2       0       2       3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `count` to get the frequency count and then with `pivot_wider` change from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
StudentGrades %>%
    count(Class, Grade = str_c('Grade_', Grade)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Grade, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  Class Grade_A Grade_B Grade_C
#   <dbl>   <int>   <int>   <int>
#1     1       1       2       2
#2     2       0       2       3
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
table(StudentGrades[c('Class', 'Grade')])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution, where `table()` + `split()` are used

```
dfout <- do.call(rbind,lapply(split(StudentGrades,StudentGrades$Class), 
       function(v) c(unique(v[1]),table(v$Grade))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  Class A B C
1 1     1 2 2
2 2     0 2 3
```